# "selected" menu item isn't selected

Tags: html, css

When the class "home" is added to an li the background image of the tab is supposed to be a different image than the black background. I'm at my wits end right now and would love any help you could offer.

You can see an example at http://www.wilwaldon.com/hornav/index.html

Thank you so much for your time, it's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant CSS selectors seem to start with `#home`, an element not present in the HTML. Try removing that.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thank you! Works fine now :)